# Can I use Skype through Empathy?

Tags: empathy, skype

I'd prefer to have my communications centralised in Empathy. Is it possible to see my Skype contacts in Empathy and use voice, video or chat?

Comment: related: http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Empathy/td-p/524705

Comment: related: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1453407

Answer (score 16):

Yes, it should be possible, but Skype must run in background and use two bridges:

- Empathy <-> libpurple  <-> Skype.

I personally use only the second one.

The Empathy/libpurple bridge is provided by [telepathy-haze](http://packages.ubuntu.com/telepathy-haze)

The libpurple/Skype bridge is provided by the [pidgin-skype](http://packages.ubuntu.com/pidgin-skype) package

Comment: The similar is valid to any other app that uses it, the Skype must be running on the background